# How to install Gradle into a Cloud 9 ide?

Tags: java, gradle, cloud9-ide

Does anyone know how I can to install Gradle into a Cloud 9 workspace?

These are my current instructions:

```
linux> wget http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-bin.zip
linux> unzip -q gradle-1.10-bin.zip -d /usr/local/                # <== GET STUCK HERE
linux> echo "export GRADLE_HOME=/usr/local/gradle-1.10" >> .profile
linux> echo "export PATH=$PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/bin" >> .profile
```

But I get the following error when I type: unzip -q gradle-1.10-bin.zip -d /usr/local/

```
quinnliu@walnutiq:~/743682 (master) $ unzip -q gradle-1.10-bin.zip -d /usr/local/
checkdir error:  cannot create /usr/local/gradle-1.10
                 Permission denied
                 unable to process gradle-1.10/.
checkdir error:  cannot create /usr/local/gradle-1.10
                 Permission denied
                 unable to process gradle-1.10/getting-started.html.
```

Is there some kind of work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you do not have permissions to make changes to `/usr/local`. `/usr` is normally owned by root. The only way you can install there is to either use `sudo` or login as `root`. If you do not have `root` access, contact the support forum to request for this or that `gradle` is installed by support.

```
$ ls -lrt /usr
total 8
drwxrwxr-x     7 root  admin    238 16 May  2011 bin
drwxr-xr-x     4 root  wheel    136 29 Jun  2011 etc
```

`gradle` can run from anywhere. So instead do this. You will have access to your home directory (`~`). The home directory can be substituted for another directory.

```
cd ~          #Go to home directory
mkdir gradle  #Create gradle directory
cd gradle     #Enter gradle directory
wget http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-bin.zip  #Download gradle
unzip -q gradle-1.10-bin.zip  #Unzip gradle
echo "export GRADLE_HOME=~/gradle" > ~/.profile
echo "export PATH=$GRADLE_HOME/bin:$PATH" > ~/.profile
source ~/.profile    #Re-read your profile
```

Then your can run `gradle --version` to check that it is working. Run `which gradle` to check that the path is `~/gradle/bin`

Comment: I followed your instructions but when I type "gradle --version" in the "gradle" folder I get bash: gradle: command not found

Comment: can you please run a `echo $PATH`, looks like `PATH` was not set. Separately, `cd ~/gradle/bin` now run `gradle --version` and that should work. If that works run `export GRADLE_HOME=~/gradle` and then `export PATH=$GRADLE_HOME/bin:$PATH` and then `cd ~;gradle --version`. `gradle` should then work from anywhere.

Comment: so I tried your export PATH commands and then run "echo $PATH" and I updated my question with what I get. Thanks for the help thus far

Comment: Just had a look and for some reason `$GRADLE_HOME\bin` is not tagged onto `$PATH`. Try this `PATH=~/gradle/bin:$PATH` and then immediately run `echo $PATH` you should see `~/gradle/bin` as the first item and then run `gradle --version`. The only thing I can think about is you are not allowed to change `$PATH` which I find hard to believe. Is your `~/gradle` all up and running? If you run `cd ~/gradle/bin;gradle --version` does that work?